# Can we customize installation of jasperserver?

Tags: java, jasperserver

I m customizing jasperserver. I want to change installation format. When we install jasper server it ask to install My Sql database. I want to change it and add Postgress database.

Is there any documentation available which will guide in customizing JasperServer and installation?
How can I do that?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the WAR file distribution to install JasperServer with postgres. You should read section 5 of the [JasperServer installation guide](http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-7-0/JasperServer-CE-Install-Guide.pdf).
It will give you step-by-step instructions on how to do it.